# LINQ - checking for null values then appending statement back to query

Tags: c#, linq

Am using Linq-to-SQL and have wrote the following query but I need to be able to check that the variable "UserRole.RoleID" is not null.

```
var MemberQuery = from SystemUser in SecurityFilter.FilteredMembers(SecurityInfo, Context, DetailLevelEnum.NameOnly)
                      join Member in Context.webpages_Memberships on SystemUser.ID equals Member.UserId
                      join UserRole in Context.webpages_UsersInRoles on Member.UserId equals UserRole.UserId
                      where Member.IsConfirmed || IncludeUnconfirmed && Filter.SelectedMemberRoles.Contains(UserRole.RoleId) // This will sometimes be null
                      select SystemUser;
```

I have thought through a number of approaches such as wrapping the query in an if / else statement or creating an anonymous type. Am not sure what the best approach would but I am trying to do something like this:

```
var MemberQuery = from SystemUser in SecurityFilter.FilteredMembers(SecurityInfo, Context, DetailLevelEnum.NameOnly)
                              join Member in Context.webpages_Memberships on SystemUser.ID equals Member.UserId
                              where Member.IsConfirmed || IncludeUnconfirmed 
                              select SystemUser;

if (Filter.SelectedMemberRoles != null)
{
    MemberQuery = MemberQuery.Where( // Somthing here 
                              join UserRole in Context.webpages_UsersInRoles on Member.UserId equals UserRole.UserId
                              where Filter.SelectedMemberRoles.Contains(UserRole.RoleId)
                              select /* Somthing */).Any();      
}
```

How can I append the second part of the query wrapped within the if condition to the original query?

Comment: You could move the `join`of the second part as `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to the first part and then add the following to your `where` of the first part:
`&& (Filter.SelectedMemberRoles == null || UserRole != null && Filter.SelectedMemberRoles.Contains(UserRole.RoleId))`

Comment: I would not use contains because it will not always work. In a situation like this I would use Query Expresssion

Comment: What's a situation where contains would fail in the above query?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var MemberQuery = (from SystemUser 
    in SecurityFilter.FilteredMembers(SecurityInfo, Context, DetailLevelEnum.NameOnly)
join Member in Context.webpages_Memberships on SystemUser.ID 
    equals Member.UserId
join _UserRole in Context.webpages_UsersInRoles on Member.UserId 
    equals _UserRole.UserId into _UserRole
from UserRole in _UserRole.DefaultIfEmpty()
where (Member.IsConfirmed || IncludeUnconfirmed )
&& (
    Filter.SelectedMemberRoles == null || UserRole != null 
    && Filter.SelectedMemberRoles.Contains(UserRole.RoleId)
)
select SystemUser)
.Distinct();
```

Comment: you should put this clause in parenthesys..  Filter.SelectedMemberRoles == null || (UserRole != null 
    && Filter.SelectedMemberRoles.Contains(UserRole.RoleId)) because the last filter is bonded at the second filter true value, otherwise you risk that the last filter it is applyed also in case of first filter null

Comment: `AND` beats `OR`, meaning that first `AND` is being interpreted and afterwards `OR`

Comment: ok, you are right.. the "AND" binds together the last two operands as one and it is evaluated only if the first operand is not null

Comment: Am getting an error saying "The name UserRole is not in scope on the right side of equals, Consider swapping the expressions on either side of equals", Which I've tried to swap but I just get another error. I've actually got the original query working in a different way but would still like to test your suggestion out.

Comment: @HitTheSky Oops, you are right. There was an underscore missing. Edited my post